# Set the dynamic values in drop down in ZF2

Tags: zend-framework2

I am using Zend Framework 2 and I would like to understand how I can add values to a drop down that is coming from a database.

The code is here:

```
$this->add(
    array(
        'name'   => 'role',
        'type'   => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select', 
        'option' => array(
            'label'        => 'Role',
            'value_option' => $roleData
        )
    )
);
```

Here the $roleData as an array and the value of array is as follows:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [cell] => admin ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [cell] => member ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 3 [cell] => guest ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 4 [cell] => Admina1 ) [4] => Array ( [id] => 5 [cell] => Admina1 ) )
```

Comment: The purpose of tags is to get attention on your question. You have removed relevant tags that people actually follow to instead use a tag that is brand new, and no one at all is following. That will only hurt your question's visibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `'value_options'` instead of `'value_option'`.

And your array has to be the following structure:

```
$options = array(
    '1' => 'admin',
    '2' => 'member',
    '3' => 'guest',
    '4' => 'Admina1',
    '5' => 'Admina1'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'yesorno',
    'type'  => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
    'options' => array(
        'label'         => 'Yes or No Label',
        'value_options' => array(
            0 => 'No', 
            1 => 'Yes'
         )
    ),
));
```